# Why more command cannot read stdin but from piped stdin?

Tags: linux, unix, command-line, pipe

I have doubt in `more` command. Normally, `more` cannot read from `stdin`, but using pipe it reads the content from stdin.

For example, While trying to execute `more` command to get the input from `stdin`, it is rejecting.

```
$ more [Enter]
Usage: more [options] file...
Options:
-d        display help instead of ring bell
-f        count logical, rather than screen lines
-l        suppress pause after form feed
-p        suppress scroll, clean screen and disblay text
-c        suppress scroll, display text and clean line ends
-u        suppress underlining
-s        squeeze multiple blank lines into one
-NUM      specify the number of lines per screenful
+NUM      display file beginning from line number NUM
+/STRING  display file beginning from search string match
-V        output version information and exit
```

But, Here it is taking input from piped `stdin`.

```
$ cat file.txt  
This is for testing purpose 
$ cat file.txt | more 
This is for testing purpose
```

I would like know how this is happening ( mean not reading from `stdin` but from piped `stdin`?

Comment: The _piped input_ is `STDIN`.

Comment: Think about it for a minute; a pager is *interactive* so it has to be able to get commands from the controlling terminal, distinct from the data source it is displaying.  If its input were the terminal, how would it know if a space character was data or a command?

Comment: If you had `more` reading your terminal as stdin, and you hit the space bar, should it interpret that as a " " to add to its displayed data, or as a command to go to the next page?  You can't write a program until you can describe what it should do, without ambiguity.  In this case that is impossible, so the program does not support this case.  But `more` will take stdin as a data source quite happily, when stdin is not connected to the controlling terminal.

Comment: I'm not sure what you've got in `file.txt`, but the text you pasted above is part of the `more` usage text, although it's odd that it would print just that. Are you literally cutting-and-pasting that output, or did you paste part of the usage message manually for some reason? I can't think of anything one could do to get that displayed, unless for some reason that's what you've got in `file.txt`. As others have pointed out, piping into more *is* reading `STDIN`.

Comment: Somehow I understood. But Still having doubt that is, how do i check (programatically) whether `stdin` is connected to a controlling terminal or not?

Comment: use `less` instead of `more`, then you won't have this problem.

Comment: @mata The non-understanding concerning how tool A internally works doesn't go away if I use tool B.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`more` discriminates on whether its standard input comes from a TTY or from elsewhere (pipe, regular file, etc.). As explained in the comments, if the input comes from a TTY, `more` refuses to run because it needs the TTY to read its command keystrokes. `cat`, on the other hand, is not interactive and doesn't deal with the TTY explicitly, so it can afford not to care whether its input is a TTY or other type of open file.

There are many other examples of Unix utilities behaving differently based on whether the standard input or output is a TTY. For example, `ls` formats its output in multiple columns, while `ls | cat` does not.

Comment: How do i check (programatically) whether `stdin` is connected to a controlling terminal or not?

Comment: @SIGKILL In C, by calling `isatty(fileno(stdin))`.